Hibernate @UpdateTimestamp not change in cascade manner
I have this Hibernate Dao classes.
@Table(name = "entity1")
public class Entity1 {
  //...other fields...

  @UpdateTimestamp
  private Date updateDate;

  @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id")
  private Set<Entity2> entity2Set;
}


@Table(name = "entity2")
public class Entity2 {
  //...other fields...

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Entity1 entity1;
}

Value of updateDate field changes if values of Entity1 change.
In case when values of Entity1 fields not change and values of Entity2 fields change - value of updateDate field not change.
Is there any way to force Hibernate to change it in this case?
I've tried to add cascade = CascadeType.ALL but it have no effect.
Of course I can set value of updateDate to null during update but in this case updateDate change even when no one field of Entity1 and Entity2 changed.

Finally I've found the solution with javax.persistence.PreUpdate:
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity1")
public class Entity1 {

  @UpdateTimestamp
  private Date updateDate;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "entity1_id")
  private Set<Entity2> entity2Set;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "entity2")
public class Entity2 {

  @PreUpdate
  public void preUpdate() {
    if (entity1 != null) {
      entity1.setUpdateDate(new Date());
    }
  }

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Entity1 entity1;
}


This is what the hibernate documentation says

Marks a property as the update timestamp of the containing entity. The
property value will be set to the current VM date whenever the owning
entity is updated.


Hello, yep, hibernate works as it is described in documentation. My question is how to propagate change of collection field item to owning entity using hibernate or something else?
